# Custom error handler in flask_restful throws NameError

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I am trying to add a custom error code to a flask_restful API, following the directions given in the [docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/extending.html) however I do not receive the correct response and I am getting a `NameError: global name 'UnsupportedMediaType' is not defined` message.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

import service

errors = {
    'UnsupportedMediaType': {
        'message': 'Unsupported Media Type',
        'status': 415
    }
}

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, errors=errors)

class Service(Resource):
    def post(self):
        if request.is_json:
            data = request.get_json()
            return service.handler(args['data'])
        else:
            raise UnsupportedMediaType

api.add_resource(Service, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store the error handler to a function. Like this:

`def error(exception):
    return {some json error data with the message 'exception'}`

now you can call the error handler as you want.

**OR**

You can use Flask error handler decorator for that. Heres the [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/errorhandling/#error-handlers)